# How to add helper methods to XCTestCase unit in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xctest

Is there a way to add a method to your XCTestCase without it being counted as a test? Something like `setUp` and `tearDown` which exists already.

One usecase would be to do a certain operation on an object in some of my test cases at specific points in time, while accessing the instance variables of the class itself (which rolls out the possibility of using static methods and external helper files)

Comment: Just add a method that doesn't start with "test".

Comment: hallelujah, thank you

Comment: @Rob you should post your comment as an actual answer so that Madeban can accept it.

Comment: @hasseg Thanks. When I posted my comment, I assumed there had to be more to the question than just the method name prefix. Good to know we answered Madeban's question, regardless.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Only methods that start with `test` will be considered tests. So, just name your helper method something that doesn't start with `test`.

By the way, I would not be inclined to put `XCTAssert` statements in your helper method. It works (the appropriate tests will fail), but in some scenarios it makes it hard to decipher which tests caused the assert in the helper method to fire.

Comment: Just to add on, in Swift you can provide a default line number parameter for a helper method, which you pass to the `XCTAssert`. That way the test failure will show up at the proper call site, not inside the helper method. Ex:

    `func checkEqual(_ string: String, _ expected: String, line: UInt = #line) {
        XCTAssertEqual(.string, expected, line: line)
    }`

Answer (score 1):

I use what Steve suggested with the optional `line` parameter in `XCTAssert` functions so the test failure appears at the callsite and append check instead of test so it isn't recognized as one.

```
private func checkSunSetsInTheEast(callLine: UInt = #line) {
    XCTFail(callLine: #line)
}
```

An alternative if you prefer your asserts to be visible in the actual test would be:

```
func testSun() {
    XCTAssert(sunSetsInEast)
}

private var sunSetsInEast: Bool { return false }
```

Keeping the test prefix and setting the test to `private` will stop them being run as tests but XCode's UI will still recognize them as a test so it's probably best to avoid prefixing test at the beginning of helper functions.